# wrong item return in view holder onclick event

Tags: android, view

Im trying to lock button after user click button on costume list.
the item of list fetched from hayoola and then i use viewholder to show data 
to user in list.
if user click accept or refuse button. the result will be passed to hayoola and 
the selected button will be disabled
Problem is after user click button wrong button getting disable. and after five click all remaining button getting disable too.

here is my adapter code :

```
static class myviewholder {
    TextView textfromhayoola;
    ImageButton buttonaccpet;
    ImageButton buttonrefuse;

}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
try {
    final myviewholder viewHolder;
    final int itemlocation = position;
    if (convertView == null) {   
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listforuser, null);
            viewHolder = new myviewholder();
            viewHolder.textfromhayoola = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textfromhayoola);
            viewHolder.buttonaccpet= (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonaccpet);
            viewHolder.buttonrefuse= (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonrefuse);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
            viewHolder = (myviewholder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        HashMap<String, String> myhayooladata= new HashMap<String, String>();
        myhayooladata = data.get(position);
        if (myhayooladata != null) {   
              viewHolder.textfromhayoola.setTag(myhayooladata.get("id_textfromhayoola"));
            viewHolder.textfromhayoola.setText(myhayooladata.get("textfromhayoola"));
            viewHolder.buttonaccpet.setTag(getItemId(position));
            viewHolder.buttonrefuse.setTag(getItemId(position));

        viewHolder.buttonaccpet.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                performOnBackgroundThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                            passdatatohayoola(viewHolder.textfromhayoola.getTag().toString(),"accpet");
                    }
                });
             arg0.findViewWithTag(viewHolder.buttonaccpet.getTag()).setEnabled(false);
             arg0.findViewWithTag(viewHolder.buttonrefuse.getTag()).setEnabled(false);      
            }
        });
        viewHolder.buttonrefuse.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                performOnBackgroundThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                            passdatatohayoola(viewHolder.textfromhayoola.getTag().toString(),"refuse");
                    }
                });
             arg0.findViewWithTag(viewHolder.buttonaccpet.getTag()).setEnabled(false);
             arg0.findViewWithTag(viewHolder.buttonrefuse.getTag()).setEnabled(false);      
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hehe. Do you think that. Just "n/number of your records" view(s) will be created?

Assume that:
If you have 100 records and 10 rows will be draw.

And 10 rows won't re-draw.

*Button accept of row 1 is disabled that mean Button accept of row 11 + n is the same. :D*

May be that's your problem.

And Please read this:

Let I tell you something about ViewHolder pattern.

When you load data to `ListView` or `GridView` or something like these.

If your data has 1000 records, ... The `ListView` doesn't load 1000 records. It's just load "n records". "n" is number of record which compatible with your screen device.

Example: n = 10.

When you scroll down, The `ListView` will load more data. In this case, each row (view of row) will re-draw.

And with `ListView` which has large data, when use scroll up or down, you will see your app will be slow... because view is re-drawing.

And ViewHolder is the pattern which help you solve that problem.

When you use `ViewHolder` pattern, Just "n" (in this example n = 10) views will be created.

So, In your problem. I can tell you that:

May be you are implemented `ViewHolder` is incorrect.

OK. Let I tell you about the solution.

```
if (convertView == null) {
   //You just findView and set for view
   // viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
   // viewHolder.yourBtn = convertView.findViewById(R.id.some_view_id);
   // convertView.setTag(viewHolder);  
} else {
   //Right here, you will get viewHolder, because convertView is not null. It mean the viewHolder is existed.
}
```

And right here, It mean every time you will set data (You won't cache data, just cache VIEW)

Assume that Your data is an object and object has property which stand for status of button.

```
MyObject {
  boolean objStatus;
}
```

and when you set data

```
viewHolder.yourBtn.setEnable(instanceOfMyObject.objStatus);
```

Comment: Thanks for a walk-through jack , one question here. in "else" condition "convertView" should be null ? becuase in first one u check for not-null "(convertView != null)"

Comment: I'm so sorry, That's my mistake. convertView == null. It's !=

Comment: sorry for my lack of knowledge but is there any difference in answer and method that im using ?
plus u are currect if i hit one button the next n button from second loading will get disable too.

Comment: Could you capture an image of your issue?

Comment: i wish i could but there is no error in logcat.
in application if i click one button it will disable itself and
the next button in second list after i scroll. exactly as u mention above.

Comment: I see. If you set button at row 1 is disable, It will be disabled. And after you scoll down, the next list (as you said) the button doesn't re-draw. That's the reason "Why button is always disable after you click".

Comment: If you don't use viewHolder, you can see the different between each other

Comment: exactly , if i dont use viewHolder button works perfectly but the list scroll comes with hiccup.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's why we use ViewHolder. But if you use ViewHolder, Please check status of your button in each row. I tell you in my answer. If you cannot solve your problem. Please add my Facebook. http://fb.com/duongtuanluc