# Add View holder to StaggeredGridView

Tags: android

I am trying to add a Viewholder to StaggeredGridView. The problem with my StaggeredGridView currently is that it scroll very slowly.

I can add a Viewholder to normal lists or GridViews but with StaggeredGridView it's
confusing to me because I have multiple layouts.

Here is my StaggeredGridView adapter:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        final LayoutParams lp;
        final View v;
        switch (position)
        {

            case 0:
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_big, parent, false);
            ImageView ImageView0 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(image_url[position]), ImageView0);
            ImageView0.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    //Do something
                }
            });
            lp = new LayoutParams(v.getLayoutParams());
            lp.span = 3;

            break;
            case 1:
                v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_normal, parent, false);
                ImageView ImageView1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(image_url[position]), ImageView1);
                ImageView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Do something
                    }
                });
                lp = new LayoutParams(v.getLayoutParams());
                lp.span = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_small, parent, false); 
                ImageView ImageView2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(image_url[position]), ImageView2);
                ImageView2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Do something
                    }
                });
                lp = new LayoutParams(v.getLayoutParams());
                lp.span = 1;
                break;
            default:
                   v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_all_other_item, parent, false);
        lp = new LayoutParams(v.getLayoutParams());
                lp.span = 1;
                break;
        }
        v.setLayoutParams(lp);
        return v;
    }
}
```

In the code above, the item layout changes base on the item's position.
Should i create multiple ViewHolder for each Case ? like three viewholder for above cases.

Comment: Why don't you try to resolve it yourself and then ask if there is a concrete problem you're encountering? You haven't even tried.

Comment: thanks for answer , as i mentiond in my question i implement viewholder in grid and listview before : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347560/wrong-item-return-in-view-holder-onclick-event
problem with staggeredgridview one is , i dont how and where should i check for null view.